# Ubuntu wont boot, fast text printed on screen

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

So I just recently installed ubuntu in a dual boot and when I booted into I got my graphics drivers and rebooted, and now I get fast moving text on my screen and it never boots up!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.s I'm not super tech savvy, but I'm also not dumb.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUwUG.jpg
Okay so it's something wrong with the drivers does anyone know what I can do from here?

Comment: After the screen where you can't read the messages what is the end result? ie purple screen or black screen with no text? Also I think you can post a picture but it appears as a link which others like myself can convert to an in-line picture.

Comment: So it boots into a purple screen, and I select ubuntu, it does the normal boot thing but then it does to a black screen with really fast moving text. And then it will just stay at the black screen with moving text. I left it there for like an hour and nothing happened. It was still fast moving text.

Comment: I wrote an answer attempting to solve the first part of your question - *How to pause scrolling text?*

Comment: Well I it wont pause it just keeps going, thankfully taking pictures I got one that is stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is called 'kernel panic' in case you want to google some more.

In the Grub menu (the first purple screen) where you select to boot ubuntu, you have other options too. One should be a **safe mode** option. You can try to boot Ubuntu in safe mode, if it works, even if you don't have GUI, you will at least have a terminal, from there remove, purge all nvidia drivers and install the version that used to work.
If safe mode works but the GUI does not work or is somehow stuck, try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal.

If you updated your kernel too and did not remove the old version, you will also be able to see the old kernel versions in the Grub menu. You can try to select one of those older versions hoping they don't have the same problem.

If you are willing to get more techy, the Grub menu also allows you to change boot parameters for the kernel, but you will need to google how and what to do, along with the model of your laptop/GPU.

If nothing works, you should save all your data and attempt a repair or reinstall using a liveUSB. When you use a liveUSB image you can mount the partitions of your system and access all the files so you can save them. Just make a separate partition and store them there if you have the space.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classic problem of this message scrolling so fast you can't see it:

```
Kernel panic – not syncing: Attempting to kill init !
```

#### Using a laptop you can try:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to stop scrolling
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to resume scrolling

#### If you have a full fledged keyboard, try

- <kbd>Scroll</kbd> Lock and <kbd>Scroll</kbd> Unlock key.

#### Other suggested solutions are

- <kbd>Pause</kbd> / <kbd>Break</kbd> key combination

[Source](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/10/14/pause-unpause-linux-boot-screen/)

Comment: Alright so I figured out what the text is, basically I installed the wrong graphics drivers and it's having a fit, so what I need to do is somehow uninstall those drivers, the issue is I cant boot into ubuntu now. The text wont stop I just tried all the combos